# How to select specific rows from a table in R?

Tags: r

I have a cars dataset in which there is an attribute of fuel type which are "Gas" and "Diesel". I want to create two separate dataframes according to those types. The dataframe should contain the entire row besides just the fuel type.

eg
Model,Make,Mfg.Year,Fuel.type,Miles
Civic,Honda,2020,Gas,1000
Sonata,Hyundai,2017,Diesel,4500
Fusion,Ford,2016,Diesel,6000
CTS,Cadillac,2018,Gas,5000

Now the result should be two different dataframes as follows

Model,Make,Mfg.Year,Fuel.type,Miles
Civic,Honda,2020,Gas,1000
CTS,Cadillac,2018,Gas,5000

and

Model,Make,Mfg.Year,Fuel.type,Miles
Sonata,Hyundai,2017,Diesel,4500
Fusion,Ford,2016,Diesel,6000

Comment: provide sample data using `dput`

Comment: Please provide your data with `dput(data)`. You should do that with the desired output too.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `split` to create a `list` of data.frames

```
lst1 <- split(df1, df1$Fuel.type)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Model = c("Civic", "Sonata", "Fusion", "CTS"), 
    Make = c("Honda", "Hyundai", "Ford", "Cadillac"), Mfg.Year = c(2020L, 
    2017L, 2016L, 2018L), Fuel.type = c("Gas", "Diesel", "Diesel", 
    "Gas"), Miles = c(1000L, 4500L, 6000L, 5000L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```